# Do we know for certain that Kylo Ren and not Rey killed that character

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, kylo-ren, rey

I am asking this question for my eight-year-old son: How do we know it was

> Kylo Ren and not Rey that turned the light saber on Snoke? 
> Clearly Snoke and the cameras are focussed on Kylo Ren, but is it possible that this is why Snoke couldn't (or wouldn't) sense Rey?

Comment: Hidden the spoilers. Good question!

Comment: Hasn't this been asked before?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

### It seems very unlikely.

The ability that Snoke uses on Rey during the scene in his throne room on board the *Supremacy* appears to be the same ability that Kylo Ren used on Rey to capture her during the events of *The Force Awakens,* that being a form of [telekinesis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Telekinesis).  Based on my understanding, what we see in these two films seems similar to [Force Stun](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_Stun), but I won't delve further into that since that ability is from *Legends* (I only brought it up because I thought that it was worth mentioning for the sake of completion, as ability that we see on film seems to have been at least inspired by Force Stun).

I can't show any footage from *The Last Jedi* at the time of this writing, but I can include a link to the scene from *The Force Awakens* where [Rey is captured by Kylo Ren](https://youtu.be/SLvxx9UC4Xk?t=257) (in case the timestamp doesn't work, the relevant portion starts at 4:17).  Here, we can see that she is almost completely immobilized, with just her eyes and perhaps some facial muscles being able to move still (although she does try to struggle against it at first).  This is one of several moments where it seems to indicate that she is not as powerful as Kylo (or can at least be easily overpowered by him depending on the circumstances), with another example being [this moment from the same video above](https://youtu.be/SLvxx9UC4Xk?t=496) (relevant portion starts at 8:16).

With Snoke, however, it seems pretty clear that she was not nearly as powerful as he was, as every attempt that she made to attack him proved to be completely fruitless, and she was completely at his mercy when he was using the aforementioned telekinesis attack on her.  This scene also demonstrates that Kylo likely wasn't as powerful as Snoke either.  This is undoubtedly why the killing blow against Snoke had to be done discreetly.

With her being virtually completely paralyzed by Snoke's attack, it would have been all the more difficult for her to use telekinesis (which we've seen her use far less than Kylo, and her feats with it were not nearly as impressive) to execute the necessary manipulations of the lightsaber during that scene.  Between that, and the fact that we saw the lightsaber moving in conjunction with Kylo's discreet hand gestures, it's far more likely that the killing blow against Snoke was entirely Kylo's own doing.

The most likely explanation as to why Snoke didn't sense that Kylo Ren was about to kill him was that [Snoke wasn't truly reading Kylo's mind, but could only sense his basic intentions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/176430/45514), which were open to interpretation just enough to fool Snoke into thinking that Kylo was intending to kill Rey during that scene.

Comment: Snoke pretty well described what will happen to the saber, just was wrong which one